# How to give Javascript callback an argument

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, closures

I'm a beginner with Javascript and I have a question about how I should provide arguments to my callbacks. Currently I have two blocks of code that are essentially identical to the below.

```
let backArrow = document.createElement("INPUT")
backArrow.type = "image"
backArrow.src = "./images/noun_back_878298.png"
backArrow.alt = "Back"
backArrow.onclick = removeModuleMobile
backArrow.id = "back-arrow"
document.body.appendChild(backArrow)
```

The only difference between them is that one instead sets backArrow.onclick to removeModule instead of removeModuleMobile. I instead would like to do something where I provide an argument to the callback but send them to the same callback thus eliminating repetitive code and having a more logical workflow. E.g.

```
backArrow.onclick = removeModule(notMobile)
```

or

```
backArrow.onclick = removeModule(mobile)
```

I don't think this is allowed as this is a function call though? I've seen a lot of things but should I be using bind() here or is there some other technique for closures. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Write a higher-order function that returns a function?

Comment: @jonrsharpe they're clearly not going to understand that.

Comment: @zfrisch *maybe* not, but they might have experience outside of JS, and it gives them something to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
backArrow.onclick = removeModule.bind(backArrow, mobile)
```

[arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
backArrow.onclick = () => removeModule(mobile);
```

or just regular function:

```
backArrow.onclick = function() {
  removeModule(mobile);
}
```

There are few differences, mostly in the value `this` will have inside `removeModule` once is called. The first one, with `bind`, is the one closest to just assign `backArrow.onclick = removeModule`, since we force (see the first argument of bind) the contextual object `this` to be `backArrow`.

In case of the arrow functions, `this` would get the value of `this` when the arrow function was declared, and for regular function (unless forced by [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) ) it would be the global object (`window` if you're in a browser).

P.S.
You might want to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of setting `onclick`: it gives you better control on events and it's more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign button.onclick as below.

```
button.onclick = () => {removeModule(mobile)}
```

Your function won't be called right away but will instead be called when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same code snippet multiple times, create a function of it with arguments that you want to change, and call that function with 'removeModuleMobile' and another time with 'removeModule'.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

```js
function removeModule() {
  console.log("not mobile");
}

function removeModuleMobile() {
  console.log("mobile");
}

function addBackArrow(clickFn) {
  let backArrow = document.createElement("INPUT")
  backArrow.type = "image"
  backArrow.src = ".jpg"
  backArrow.alt = "Back"
  backArrow.onclick = clickFn;
  backArrow.id = "back-arrow"

  document.body.appendChild(backArrow)
}

addBackArrow(removeModule);
addBackArrow(removeModuleMobile);
```

---

### Explanation:

To turn lines of code into a `Function` you have to wrap the lines with a **function declaration**. You can think of this like declaring a variable with `let`, `var`, or `const`, except the word that you use is `function`.

A function declaration contains **three parts**

---

**Firstly**: A variable name ( like `addBackArrow` )

```
function addBackArrow
```

**Secondly**: Any expected variables that might be passed into the function to be used, like *name*, *age*, or in this case, a function.

When a variable is passed to the function we give it a name so that we can reference it within the function.

These variables are called **arguments** for our **function** and they are written after our function name within parentheses.

In our case we will be passing in a function that be triggered when the element is clicked.

We can call it `clickFn`  ( *fn* is typical shorthand for **function**, thus "clickFn" is read as "Click Function" )

```
function addBackArrow( clickFn )
```

**Lastly**: We place the lines of code to be run *inside* our **function**.

The lines are placed between *braces*  ( `{` and `}` )

```
function addBackArrow(clickFn) {
    ...

  backArrow.onclick = clickFn;
}
```

In the above you'll notice that we changed `onclick` to the value of `clickFn`. This is because we will be passing into `addBackArrow` the function we want to be called when the element is clicked.

---

To call `addBackArrow` and execute the code inside of it twice, *once with each function*, you write the name of the **function** and provide it with **arguments** in parentheses:

```
 addBackArrow( removeModule );
 addBackArrow( removeModuleMobile );
```

---

### Full Code:

```
function addBackArrow(clickFn) {
  let backArrow = document.createElement("INPUT")
  backArrow.type = "image"
  backArrow.src = ".jpg"
  backArrow.alt = "Back"
  backArrow.onclick = clickFn;
  backArrow.id = "back-arrow"

  document.body.appendChild(backArrow)
}

addBackArrow(removeModule);
addBackArrow(removeModuleMobile);
```